# How do I know if the 'usedforsecurity' flag is supported by hashlib.md5?

Tags: python, c, security, md5, libcrypto

When I run the following on my Macbook, I get the error:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(usedforsecurity=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: openssl_md5() takes no keyword arguments
```

But when I run it on my Linux box, it works!

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(usedforsecurity=False)
<md5 HASH object @ 0x7f763c1375d0>
```

My problem is, I need to run some safe, non-security related code on my FIPS enabled system (such as managing a cache of user requests which hashes the user query as an MD5 string). Using the `usedforsecurity` flag prevents a FIPs exception.

This works fine, except when I want to test my code on my Macbook. My Macbook's "libcrypto" library apparently doesn't support this `usedforsecurity` flag. Is there a good way to detect if the underlying C bindings behind `hashlib.md5` support this  flag or not?

Comment: Try it and see if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `hashlib.new('md5', usedforsecurity=False)` instead of `hashlib.md5(usedforsecurity=False)` it will not raise exception, even if the keyword argument is not supported.

Comment: Thank you!  Was this API added to `hashlib` after my question was posted?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem with FIPS and hashlib.md5(), but I was able to do this to check:

```
>>> import hashlib, inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(hashlib.new)
ArgSpec(args=['name', 'string', 'usedforsecurity'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=('', True))
```

On Python 3+, `getargspec` is deprecated, so `getfullargspec` should be used instead. The data structure is similar, but `usedforsecurity` is in the `kwonlyargs` field now.

```
>>> inspect.getfullargspec(hashlib.new)
FullArgSpec(args=['name', 'data'], varargs=None, varkw='kwargs', defaults=(b'',), kwonlyargs=['usedforsecurity'], kwonlydefaults={'usedforsecurity': True}, annotations={})
```